# How to set environment variable in docker container system wide at container start for all users?

Tags: docker

I need to set some environment variable for all users and processes inside docker container. It should be set at container start, not in `Dockerfile`, because it depends on running environment.

So the simple `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN echo 'export TEST=test' >> '/root/.bashrc'
```

works well for interactive sessions
`docker run -ti test bash`
then 
`env`
and there is `TEST=test`

but when `docker run -ti test env` there is no `TEST`

I was trying

```
RUN echo 'export TEST=test' >> '/etc/environment'
RUN echo 'TEST="test"' >> '/etc/environment'
RUN echo 'export TEST=test' >> /etc/profile.d/1.sh
ENTRYPOINT export TEST=test
```

Nothing helps.

Why I need this. I have `http_proxy` variable inside container automatically set by docker, I need to set another variables, based on it, i.e. `JAVA_OPT`, do it system wide, for all users and processes, and in running environment, not at build time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a script which would be an entrypoint:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# if env variable is not set, set it
if [ -z $VAR ];
then
    # env variable is not set
    export VAR=$(a command that gives the var value);
fi

# pass the arguments received by the entrypoint.sh
# to /bin/bash with command (-c) option
/bin/bash -c $@
```

And in Dockerfile I would set the entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT entrypoint.sh
```

Now every time I run `docker run -it <image> <any command>` it uses my script as entrypoint so will always run it before the command then pass the arguments to the right place which is `/bin/bash`.

#### Improvements

The above script is enough to work if you are always using the entrypoint with arguments, otherwise your `$@` variable will be empty and will give you an error `/bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument`. A easy fix is an if statement:

```sh
if [ ! -z $@ ];
then
    /bin/bash -c $@;
fi
```

Comment: @AntonOvsyannikov be aware of my last edit, maybe it will be useful for you!

Comment: It's not working if I'd like to `docker exec` something in running container, i.e. `bash` or `env`, for those sessions variables still not set :(

Answer (score 0):

Setting the parameter in ENTRYPOINT would solve this issue.

In docker file  pass parameter in ENTRYPOINT