# docker-compose can't set env values automatically

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment

There is a `start.sh` script under the application:

scripts/start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

source /env/set.sh
```

env/set.sh content:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DB_USERNAME=a
export DB_PASSWORD=b
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    expose:
      - "5000"
    command: scripts/start.sh
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
```

After run `docker-compose build && docker-compose up`, login into the container, the env values had not been set. But should run `source /env/set.sh` manually. 
Why didn't `command: scripts/start.sh` work?

Comment: Do you really need to set it after the container has started? Otherwise, you could use docker-compose environments

Comment: you don't need to do such a hard work. there is a nice feature that does just that and it's called [environments](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

Comment: @VitorFalcão @MeysamAzad `env_file` seems a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you need to set it after the container has started and can't use the docker-compose environment variables.

You are sourcing the script that exports all the variables needed but then you close this bash session, what you need is to make the exports permanent. I described a way to do it in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484003/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-docker-container-system-wide-at-container-sta/56484272#56484272).

What you need is an entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/bash

# if env variable is not set, set it
if [ -z $DB_USERNAME ];
then
    # env variable is not set
    export DB_USERNAME=username;
fi

# pass the arguments received by the entrypoint.sh
# to /bin/bash with command (-c) option
/bin/bash -c $@
```

Then add this script as entrypoint in your docker-compose file.